# Reactjs map function how to show different value for each item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the map function to display each item in an array, and there is also a star rating system using Material UI where the user can click one of the stars. But when the user clicks a rating for a specific item, all the other items in the array change to that value too - I want it to be unique per item, if that makes sense.
Here is the code (I'm using class components in react).

```
<List>
  {this.state.quizzes.map((item) => {
    return (
      <ListItem button key={`${this.topic}-${item.quiz_title}`}>
        <div className="rating" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
          <Rating
            name="hover-feedback"
            value={this.state.value}
            precision={1}
            max={3}
            onChange={(e, newValue) => {
              this.setValue(newValue)
            }}
            onChangeActive={(e, newHover) => {
              this.setHover(newHover)
            }}
          />
          {this.state.value !== null && (
            <Box ml={2}>
              {
                this.labels[
                  this.state.hover !== -1 ? this.state.hover : this.state.value
                ]
              }
            </Box>
          )}
        </div>
      </ListItem>
    )
  })}
</List>
```

How can I make it so the value the user picks doesn't change the values of other items as well? There will be a lot of items in the array so I don't want to make a variable for each one.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
 return (
      {this.state.quizzes.map((item) => (
        <List>
          <ListItem button key={`${this.topic}-${item.quiz_title}`}>
                  <div className="rating" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                    <Rating
                      name="hover-feedback"
                      value={this.state.value}
                      precision={1}
                      max={3}
                      onChange={(e, newValue) => {
                        this.setValue(newValue)
                      }}
                      onChangeActive={(e, newHover) => {
                        this.setHover(newHover)
                      }}
                    />
                    {this.state.value !== null && (
                      <Box ml={2}>
                        {
                          this.labels[
                            this.state.hover !== -1 ? this.state.hover : this.state.value
                          ]
                        }
                      </Box>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </ListItem>
        </List>

      ))}

)
```